# How to plot a graph with fixed Frame width and height while keep PlotRange Automatic?

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot a graph and set Frame width and height by given numbers. However, I found I could only fix the Frame height, the Frame width varys with data plotted. For example, compare

```
 img1 = ListPlot[{0.5*#, 5 #} & /@ Range@100, Joined ->True,
PlotRange -> {Automatic, {100, 300}}, PlotStyle -> Black,  
LabelStyle -> 18, ImageSize -> 1 -> {5, 1.6}, Frame -> True, 
Joined -> True, FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y"}, AspectRatio -> 3]
```

and

```
img2 = ListPlot[{0.1*# + 1, 5 #} & /@ Range@100, Joined -> True, 
PlotRange -> {Automatic, {100, 300}}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
LabelStyle -> 18, ImageSize -> 1 -> {5, 1.6}, Frame -> True, 
Joined -> True, FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y"}, AspectRatio -> 3]
```

The Frames of `img1` and `img2` have same height but different width. How to make their width equal?

I'm using Mathematica 12 on windows 10.

Comment: The problem is that you're specify conflicting options - `ImageSize -> 1 -> {5, 1.6}` specifies that 1 unit in the plot should correspond to 5 & 1.6 in x & y respectively. And this seems to take priority over `AspectRatio`. If you change it to `ImageSize -> 1 -> 1.6`, it will work as expected

Comment: To adjust for different horizontal plot ranges in `img1` and `img2`, change the image size option in `img2` to `ImageSize -> 1 -> {5  50/11, 1.6}`